# Cómo puedo evitar que el navegador me solicite el guardado de constraseñas?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, contraseña

Buen día a todos
Estoy en la busqueda de un método para evitar que el navegador me pida el guardado de las contraseñas, mi aplicación está construida con JSF2.2 usando primeFaces.
El código utilizado es:

```
    <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="panelLogin" style="width:30%">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Número de Cliente Empresarial" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                        <p:inputText id="cliente" maxlength="18" onkeyup="validarClienteNum()"
                                    autocomplete="false" onchange="cambiotipocli()" 
                                    type="#{LoginMB.tipoCampoCli}"
                                    disabled="#{LoginMB.disNumCli}"
                                    style="width:100%!important; font-weight: normal !important;"
                                    value="#{LoginMB.numeroClienteEmpre}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Tipo de Identificación" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                        <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoDocumento" disabled="#{LoginMB.disList}" 
                                        value="#{LoginMB.tipoIdentificacionSelec}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{DominiosMB.tipoIdentificacionIt}"/>
                        </p:selectOneMenu>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Número de Documento" style="font-weight: bold"/>
                        <p:inputText id="documento" maxlength="18" onkeyup="validarDocumentoNum()"
                                    autocomplete="false" onchange="cambioDoc()" 
                                    disabled="#{LoginMB.disNumDoc}" type="#{LoginMB.tipoCampoCliente}"
                                    style="width:100%!important;font-weight: normal !important;"
                                    value="#{LoginMB.numeroDocumento}" />
                        <p:outputLabel value="Clave Personal" style="font-weight: bold"
                                       rendered="#{LoginMB.banClavePersonal}"/>
                        <p:password id="contrasena" autocomplete="false"
                                    style="width:100%!important;font-weight: normal !important;"
                                    rendered="#{LoginMB.banClavePer}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Clave Dinámica" style="font-weight: bold"
                                       rendered="#{LoginMB.banToken}"/>
                        <p:password id="token" value="#{LoginMB.claveTok}" maxlength="8"
                                    onkeyup="validarNumerico()" autocomplete="false"
                                    style="width:100%!important; font-weight: normal !important;"
                                    rendered="#{LoginMB.banTok}"/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Clave Virtual Empresarial" style="font-weight: bold"
                                       rendered="#{LoginMB.banClaveVirtual}"/>
                        <p:password id="clVirtual" value="#{LoginMB.clavevirtual}" maxlength="8"
                                    onkeyup="validarNumerico()" autocomplete="false"
                                    style="width:100%!important; font-weight: normal !important;"
                                    rendered="#{LoginMB.banClaveVirtual}"/>
                    </p:panelGrid>
```

Como pueden ver el formulario ya tiene el autocomplete = off y cada uno de los campos de texto del primeFaces tiene el autocomplete = false; a pesar de esto los navegadores siguen solicitandome el guardado de la contraseña. Gracias por su colaboración

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de enviar el formulario, puedes copiar la información de los campos de usuario y contraseñas a inputs hidden, luego borras por javascript la información de los campos visibles o los campos como tal (usuario y contraseñas) y finalmente en tu backend bean haces las validaciones contra lo que está en los inputs hidden.

Lo anterior lo puedes lograr con un `onsubmit` en el formulario de JSF.

Si estás usando JAAS para la autenticación, puedes usar la misma estrategia pero asignando a los inputs hidden los nombres necesarios de JASS (j_username, j_password).

Los navegadores al no detectar un usuario y contraseña no preguntarán por el guardado de contraseñas.

Comment: Gracias @Jucaaalpa fue de gran ayuda y funciona correctamente